# Questions about code for checkbook balancing program in c++

Tags: c++, function

I'm trying to write a program to balance a checkbook in c++. Here are my exact instructions

> Write a program that will represent one month’s transactions in your checkbook. Prompt the 
>   user for a starting balance and then allow the user to enter as many transactions as desired.
>
> Transactions should be in the form of C500 (for a check of $500), or D250 (for a deposit of $250), or E (for End of month).
>
> Each transaction carries service charges as follows: $.15 for every check and $.10 for every deposit; also, there is a one time service charge of $5 if the balance falls below $500 any time during the month and a $10 service charge for every check written that results in a negative balance.
>
> Finally, you are to give the user a warning if their balance is between $0 and $50. Run the demo program and pay close attention to the desired output.
>
> (Note that the current balance and total service charges are printed after each transaction, but service charges are not subtracted from the balance until the user declares E for end of month).

My code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

void MoneyFunct(float &CashLeft, float StartBal, char TransacType,
    float Transac, int Q, float TotalServiceCharge);

int main() {
    char TransacType;
    float StartBal;
    float Transac;
    float CashLeft = StartBal;
    float TotalServiceCharge;
    cout << "Enter your starting balance: ";
    cin >> StartBal;
    do {
        cout << "Now enter your transaction."
            << "Enter E when your month has ended." << endl;
        cout << "Enter transaction type: ";
        cin >> TransacType;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Enter the amount for your transaction: ";
        cin >> Transac;
        cout << endl;
        MoneyFunct;
        cout << "You have $" << CashLeft 
            << " remaining in your account" << endl
            << "Your total service charges are "
            << TotalServiceCharge << endl;
    } while (TransacType != 'E');

    CashLeft = CashLeft + TotalServiceCharge;
    cout << endl << "Your final balance is " 
        << CashLeft << "." << endl
        << "Your total service charges are "
        << TotalServiceCharge << "." << endl
        << "Thanks for using the checkbook balancer!" << endl;
    return 0;
}

void MoneyFunct(float &CashLeft, float StartBal, char TransacType, 
    float Transac, int Q, float TotalServiceCharge)
{
    Q == 4;
    TotalServiceCharge = 0;
    if (TransacType == 'C') {
        CashLeft = CashLeft - Transac;
        TotalServiceCharge = TotalServiceCharge + 0.15;
    } else if (TransacType == 'D') {
        CashLeft = CashLeft + Transac;
        TotalServiceCharge=TotalServiceCharge+0.10;
    }

    if (CashLeft < 500) {
        while (Q == 1) {
            cout << "Your balance has fallen below $500."
               << "A one time charge of $5 will be subtracted "
               << "from your balance." << endl;
            TotalServiceCharge = TotalServiceCharge+5;
            Q++;
        }
    }

    if (CashLeft <= 50 && CashLeft >= 0) {
        cout << "Your balance is lower than $50." <<
            << "If your balance becomes negative "
            << "you will be charged $10" << endl;
    }

    if (CashLeft < 0) {
        cout << "Your balance has become negative." <<
            << "A $10 charge will be subtracted "
            << "from your balance." << endl;
        TotalServiceCharge = TotalServiceCharge+10;
    }
}
```

This is returning something that resembles this:

```
Enter your starting balance: 500
Now enter your transaction. Enter E when your month has ended.
Enter transaction type: D

Enter the amount for your transaction: 500

You have $4.42913e+032 remaining in your account
Your total service charges are nan
Now enter your transaction. Enter E when your month has ended.
Enter transaction type: E

Enter the amount for your transaction: 500

You have $4.42913e+032 remaining in your account
Your total service charges are nan

Your final balance is nan.
Your total service charges are nan.
Thanks for using the checkbook balancer!

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 7.874 s
Press any key to continue.
```

The balance that it returns is large enough for me to assume that I have an infinite loop somewhere.

Comment: What do you think the line `MoneyFunct;` does?  (It's not a function call.)  Also, please don't include such long strings in the code.  The point of StackOverflow Q&A is to reduce your question to the minimal issue that is getting you confused...and so all the long-winded prompts and messages get in the way.  You really should reduce your program way down to just a single point of confusion, as opposed to giving us your whole problem statement and solution.  If you have to ask multiple smaller focused questions, that's better than "one big one" with your full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This...

```
float CashLeft = StartBal;
```

...appears before `StartBal` has been initialised by `cin >> StartBal`, so you have Undefined Behaviour having read from an uninitialised variable.  Just move the line above to be after the `cin >> StartBal;`.

Separately, it's a good habit to check whether your streaming operations actually work.  For example:

```
if (cin >> StartBal)
    CashLeft = StartBal;
else
{
    std::cerr << "unable to read StartBal from cin\n";
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tony. After doing that, the output is always that there are $500 in the account, could anyone help me with why the deposits and withdrawals aren't changing the value that is output?

Comment: @imdabes Please note what I said about `MoneyFunct;` not invoking the function.  That line just evaluates to the value of a function pointer, and is discarded.  If you want to call it with parameters you need to actually call it as in `MoneyFunct(CashLeft, StartBal, TransacType, Transac, /* whatever Q is */, TotalServiceCharge);`  Or something.

Comment: @imdabes: HostileFork has a solid point... have you tried after correcting the `MoneyFunct` call?

Comment: That made it work, thank you both so much! @HostileFork I'll take your advice on how much code to put in the next time I post, thanks again!

Comment: Everything is now working except for the service charge. I'm wondering how to make it so rather than outputting the service charge for only the previous transaction it will output the total service charges from all transactions? thanks

Comment: @imdabes: currently, `TotalServiceCharge` is accepted by `MoneyFuct` as a by-value argument... that means `MoneyFunct` operates on a copy, and changes within `MoneyFunct` - like additions - are lost when `MoneyFunct` returns.  You should 1) make the `MoneyFunct`'s `TotalServiceCharge` argument a reference, and 2) set it to ``0`` when you define the variable in `main()`, and do not reset it to 0 every time `MoneyFunct` is called.

Comment: It was having it set to 0 within the function itself, which was in the loop, that was doing it, thank you SO much!!

Comment: The purpose of Q was to make it so that the service charge of 5 dollars for falling below 500 only occurred once, and after that Q was increased by 1, so the $5 service charge could only occur once in the program. However it's occurring every time that after a transaction the amount in the balance is lower than 500. I changed the while loop for (Q == 1) to a do while with the same thing after the while. Is there a way to do what I want that works and, preferably, is easier?

Comment: @imdabes Same kind of thing we talked about for `TotalServiceCharge` - initialise Q in `main()`, pass it in by reference.  You can use a `bool` that's false initially and set true when a service charge has been enacted, then use `if (!Q)` to prevent further charges....